# Cocoa Referencing NSArray Values

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have a string of data "latitude,longitude,location" stored as an NSString.

I want to reference the data in different ways so I stored it into an NSArray.

I then store the data in easy to read NSString values and want to reuse them a couple times.

```
- (IBAction)convertButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
NSString *returnData = @"49.1002,-102.1253,12-03-22-W3";

explode = [returnData componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

Latitude    = [explode objectAtIndex: 0];
Longitude   = [explode objectAtIndex: 1];
Location    = [explode objectAtIndex: 2];
Query.text  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", Location];
Result.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", Latitude, Longitude];
}
```

I then set these values into UILabel values.  I have no issues at this point.  The next thing I want the user to be able to do is plot this data onto a MKMapView.  So I have a UIButton setup to plot the data.  When it is clicked, a new ViewController slides into view and I try to pass the data, however I am not having any luck.  Instead of passing data, my application crashes.

```
- (IBAction)plotButtonPressed:(id)sender;
{
ShowMapViewController *showMap = [[ShowMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

showMap.currentLocation = Location;

showMap.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:showMap animated:YES];
}
```

I guess my simple question for this is... How do I properly store my variables so that I can pass them onto my ShowMapViewController.

Comment: What error does it crash with?  Also, if you want ShowMapViewController to plot the location on the map, don't you also need to pass it the latitude and longitude?

Comment: Why not make a model object that owns the latitude, longitude, and location as properties? Then you don't need to deal with string parsing and unparsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the ivar `Longitude` in two places. In `convertButtonPressed:` you are extracting it from an array using `objectAtIndex:` and in `plotButtonPressed:` you are reusing the value.

Note that when you get the value for `Location` you are not using a method that starts with `new`, `alloc`, or `copy`, which means that, if you want the value to live beyond the current autorelease pool, you must manually `retain` or `copy` it. You aren't doing that here, so some time between `convertButtonPressed:` and `plotButtonPressed:`, the autorelease pool is being popped, and your object deallocated, leaving you with a dangerous dangling pointer.

Comment: Relevant documentation link: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I managed to solve it last night by adding retain to my NSArray line.